Is the epicurean problem of evil, not so much a problem?
The epicurean problem of evil is a problem that makes it difficult to conclude the truth of a supernatural being that is onibenevolent and omnipotent.
If God is onibenevolent and omnipotent how does that God allow evil to happen in the world, either by man or natural processes, Why can't that God prevent it if he is omnipotent and benevolent?
My answer to this question is would God begin with a perfect world in which we could all live peacefully and without pain or suffering and evil?
How can you reward the heaven of this world to its occupants, with heaven in the afterlife?
As a side note is reward not a fundamental system of belief to any religion?

Reward for moral behaviour. In a world without evil can anyone perform an immoral act?

I'm puzzled has anyone asked this question before? and asked a reasonable rebi

Have you got any questions that would question the philosophical norm?

So basically, the argument goes like this:

If God is all powerful, He could prevent evil.
If God is all loving, He would prevent evil.
Evil exists.
Therefore, no all-powerful, all-loving God exists.

The problem is with premise #2.  It assumes that an all-good God would not possibly allow evil, even for a greater good.  But how could we ever know this?  We simply can't.  Our intelligence and perspective is severely limited for that kind of judgment.
From the Bible, it doesn't have to do with God needing evil so that heaven can be a"motivation" for doing good; for example, before Adam and Eve fell, the world was perfect.  Rather, I think that biblically, it has to do with God wanting to create us with a certain freedom of the will.  He wanted to create people who could freely receive or reject Him.  He knew this would result in great evil, including the entire human race falling into sin; but for those who will receive the love of Jesus Christ and His sacrifice for their sin and be saved, God works all things, even evil, together for their ultimate good (Romans 8:28).  And I imagine that in the end, heaven will be all the more sweet because God decided to create free will.
And so if we modify premise #2 to take our limited perspective into account, and also add God's existence as another premise, we end up with this revised argument:

If God is all powerful, He could prevent evil.
If God is all loving, He would prevent evil, unless it were for a greater good.
Evil exists.
An all-powerful, all-loving God exists.
Therefore, God allows the evil that exists for some greater good.


And we know that all things work together for good to them that love God, to them who are the called according to his purpose.  (Romans 8:28)


Are you suggesting that the god's greater good is a number of humans choosing to love and follow the god?

It should be obvious that the battery will not run without negative and positive sides.
Georg Wilhelm Friedrich Hegel did research in detail on the balance of opposites in our reality.
Kind and loving are equally balanced with evil and destructive in this world.
In terms of rewards, in our lives, evil deeds are sometimes rewarded on par with kind deeds.

the battery will not run without negative and positive sides Superb. More like Theres no battery
